# Roboframework - Selenium - find all HREF containing specific text

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

my goal is to find all HREF links in a webpage containing specific text.
Using Chrome DevTools I tested in "find elements":

```
[href*='photo/?fbid']
```

and it works pretty fine as it returns them all.

When I try to include it in the robotframework script:

```
 ${elements}=    Get WebElements     xpath://[href*='photo/?fbid']
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        Log    ${element.text}
        Log    ${element}
    END
```

I obtain error message:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[href*='photo/?fbid'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//[href*='photo/?fbid']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
```

I've tryed to check on the documentation but I don't understand what is the right syntax.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is you are mixing xpath and CSS. The selector you used is a CSS selector and then you are passing it as a XPATH. So you can do it in two ways

**XPATH**

```
Get WebElements     xpath://a[contains(@href,'photo/?fbid')]
```

**CSS**

```
Get WebElements     css:a[href*='photo/?fbid']
```

Comment: Thanks, acually when I get all the elements I got this strings => ${element} = <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ba524dc8a3736f73410b497adec941ec", element="1254ad02-1790-43a0-84c9-d05e6a051883")>. Do you know for all the Get WebElements how to get the actual HTTP link?

Comment: That is because you printed the element instead of printing its href attribute.  Look at https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute